# Html/Css Triangle with pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a triangle shape with the pseudo elements. like the one in the image below.[image]

But this is what i get. [image]

Here is what i have tried this far.

```
.container .form--container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 130px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    transform: translate(-1rem, -100%);
    border-left: 1.5rem solid #979797;
    border-right: 1.5rem solid #979797;
    border-bottom: 1.5rem solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is with the use of border. you can check this link [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work) and you will understand how border works and why you get this output.

An alternative solution is to use **rotation** and **border** like this :

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
  background: #f2f2f5;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  top: -11px;
  left: 13px;
  background: #f2f2f5;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

And in case you want your box with the arrow to be transparent, here is another trick to achieve it (as the above solution consider solid color as background):

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 background-image:linear-gradient(to right,yellow,pink);
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top:transparent; /*make border-top transparent*/
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
  /* Use gradient to mimic the border top with a transparent gap */
  background:linear-gradient(to right,black 10px,transparent 10px,transparent 39px,black 39px) top/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid ;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  top: -11px;
  left: 14px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Here is another version with dashed border:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 background-image:linear-gradient(to right,yellow,pink);
}

.box {
  border: 1px dashed;
  border-top:transparent; /*make border-top transparent*/
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
  background:
   repeating-linear-gradient(to right,black 0,black 3px,transparent 3px,transparent 6px) top left/10px 1px,
   repeating-linear-gradient(to right,black 0,black 3px,transparent 3px,transparent 6px) top right/calc(100% - 40px) 1px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 1px dashed;
  border-left: 1px dashed;
  top: -11px;
  left: 13px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Could it theoretically also be done with `clip-path`? Like this one: `clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 40%, 10% 40%, 15% 0, 20% 40%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%);` or would that cause problems?