# Why is this CSS arrow border not black?

Tags: css, css-selectors, tooltip, border

I have taken a tooltip from another Stack Overflow post, and slightly modified it. It looks like this:

[image: Tooltip image]

Generated from the following code:

```css
.up-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.up-arrow:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    bottom: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: black;
} 

.up-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 141px;
    bottom: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div href="#" class="up-arrow">Button with Up Arrow</div>
```

If you look very closely, you can see that the color of the :before element is not actually black, it is #77777.

[image: Eyedropper check]

This problem has left my coworkers and I stumped. It is consistent across browsers. Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Anti-aliasing smoothes the line to avoid "jaggies" (square pixels along the diagonal). This is definitely a feature, not a bug.

Comment: It outputs #808080 here in stack overflow's code snippets thingy on Chrome. I think you've found a proper ghost in the machine.

Comment: make the bottom 99% instead of 100%

Comment: here is another post to get more ways to avoid this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956092/html-css-triangle-with-pseudo-elements/47956145#47956145

Comment: Definitely just anti-aliasing.

Comment: If you color sample the corners of your box you'll also discover they're also anti-aliased and lighter than #000

Comment: I see. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.up-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.up-arrow:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    bottom: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: black;
} 

.up-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 141px;
    top: -17px;
    bottom: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 9px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div href="#" class="up-arrow">Button with Up Arrow</div>
```

Your problem is antialiasing, which is trying to make your line look smooth. You *can* make it true black by moving the `:after` element 1 pixel or so further away from the diagonals, so that the line is thicker and antialiasing only affects the outside pixels not the inner pixels, but whether this is desirable is another question. It looks slightly odd.

Said effect is achieved in the snippet above by adding `top: -17px` to the  `:after` element.