# CSS onhover the caret part of a full CSS chat bubble

Tags: html, css

Working on a chat bubble:

```css
.bubble {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: rgb(219, 218, 218);
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border:rgb(107, 107, 107) solid 2px;
}

.bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px 5px 0;
    border-color: rgb(219, 218, 218)  transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -5px;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 43%;
}

.bubble:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 6px 0;
    border-color: rgb(107, 107, 107) transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: -6px;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 43%;
}

.bubble:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

The onhover is currently not working for the caret part of the chat bubble. The desired result is obviously the whole chat bubble being filled up when there is an onhover event. I tried (not a CSS wiz):

```
.bubble:hover,  .bubble:hover:before, .bubble:hover:after{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I also tried a lot of different stuff but it doesn't seem to work. How do I fix this?

Comment: as a side note, you can use only one pseudo element to achieve this, here is an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956092/html-css-triangle-with-pseudo-elements/47956145#47956145

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add

```
.bubble:hover:after {
  border-color: red transparent;
}
```

because the small triangle is actually the border of the `:after` element.

```css
.bubble {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 35px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: rgb(219, 218, 218);
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: rgb(107, 107, 107) solid 2px;
}

.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px 5px 0;
  border-color: rgb(219, 218, 218) transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -5px;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 43%;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 6px 0;
  border-color: rgb(107, 107, 107) transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
  bottom: -9px;
  left: 43%;
}

.bubble:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.bubble:hover:after {
  border-color: red transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply this:

```
.bubble:hover::after {
      border-color: red  transparent;
    }
```

```css
.bubble {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 35px;
height: 20px;
padding: 0px;
background: rgb(219, 218, 218);
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-moz-border-radius: 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
border:rgb(107, 107, 107) solid 2px;
}

.bubble:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 6px 5px 0;
border-color: rgb(219, 218, 218)  transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
margin-left: -5px;
bottom: -6px;
left: 43%;
}

.bubble:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 7px 6px 0;
border-color: rgb(107, 107, 107) transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
margin-left: -6px;
bottom: -9px;
left: 43%;
}

.bubble:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.bubble:hover::after {
  border-color: red  transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```