# Box arrows top side border radius

Tags: html, css

I want to give border radius on top side of arrows. As per given attached image.[image]

js fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaykaneriya/6Lzuh5aq/14/)

```
let me know
```

Comment: Please fix your links and consider reading how to create a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then update your question so we can help you.

Comment: check you Question again. there's no link

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow. Now i have edited question and added fiddle link.

Comment: check this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/47956145/8620333 you can easily add a border radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/f6gqkodm/

Check this link I have updated **.block-minicart:before** styles to meet your needs

```css
.minicart-wrapper .ui-dialog .block-minicart:before {
    top: -9px;
    right: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #c1c1c1 #ffffff #ffffff #c1c1c1;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    background: white;
}
```

[image]