# CSS triangle with border (connecting to other border)

Tags: css

I want to make a speech bubble like the image below with an outline/border. The arrow is a square with two borders, rotated by 45 degress.
It does work, but the borders do not connect perfectly, as you can see when you zoom in.

Is this even cleanly solvable with CSS? If not, how would you solve it?

[image]

Source: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-simple-triangle-borders-with-css-665d26372825

Comment: just change the top value to `-12.5px`. it should fix it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47956092/8620333

Comment: Since it's two seperate items alignen them on all zoom levels will be tricky I imagine. Maybe you can use an SVG for the border.

Comment: @SumitSurana : Looks better now, but there remains a kind of antialiasing artifact at the "splice". Look here: https://iili.io/UthHOJ.md.jpg

Comment: Update: "background-clip: padding-box;" removes the color from the splice.

Comment: Update 2: Unfortunately, the value depends on the browser and the browser zoom. In Chrome and Firefox the element even jumps when I scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can probably just shift it outwards by one pixel to fix this, i.e. change `top: -12px` to `top: -13px`